# Captcha for Joomla Administrator Login Panel

Tags: php, joomla

I am facing problem from last two days. I need Captcha for Joomla Admin panel. There are many plugins available but no on is working joomla admin panel. Please help me out.How i can do this?

Regards,
Manpreet Singh

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

As you say there are no plugins for `/administrator` login.

If you wanted to write one you have to create a system plugin and a login component.

To catch the login a `system` plugin for either the `onAfterRoute` or `onAfterDispatch` would be need to adjust the destination to point to your own version of the `/adminstrator` version of`com_login`.

Then create a new `com_mylogin` - you could easily adapt the `com_login` component to do what you want.

Having said all of that why do you need a captcha - it's rarely effective if someone is determined. Captcha is only really useful against not very bright bots.

There are lots you can do:

- simplest mechanism is to apply a realm password to `/administrator`...
- or use [some of the recommended ways of securing Joomla! including `/administrator`](http://docs.joomla.org/Category%3aSecurity_Checklist)
- add a [Login Protection extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection) like the [JSecure plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/12254)?

Answer (score 0):

I know quite a bit of time has elapsed, but I hope I can provide a helpful contribution to anyone else looking for the same solution.

I would suggest looking into using the excellent Admin Tools extension from AkeebaBackup.com and in particular the "two factor" authentication facility.  This adds another level of security by requiring a key provided by a google app from a smartphone.  I know this isn't a captcha facility, but it might be a better solution to protect the Joomla backend.

Hope that helps.

Brian